# Clamping diode current in flyback converter

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

In an RCD clamping circuit configuration of flybacks,

Could anyone explains to me how the following relationship is derived ?

$$ \ {I_d}=I_{peak}  \frac{\Delta t - t}{\Delta t}  $$

The equation describes the current circulating through the clamping diode when it conducts (When the drain voltage hits the clamping voltage)

The circuit and graphs are shown below:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concentrate on the red triangle: -

[image]

And think about t varying relative to the base of the triangle starting at 0 and ending at Δt. When t = 0, \$I_d = I_{PEAK}\$ and when t = Δt, \$I_d = 0\$.

Comment: But the diode starts conducting when the $ V_{Clump}= V_{clamp} $, I think the switch is open, there is still a current going through the capacitor for short time than the diode starts conducting

Comment: As soon as the switch opens, the back emf will force current into the clamp. Sure, the switch’s parasitic capacitor will need to charge first but I believe that time is ignored by the graph.

Comment: When the switch opens, the current first flows in the capacitance lumped at the drain and it slightly depletes the energy stored in the leakage inductance. As a result, the peak current in the RCD diode is not exactly \$I_{peak}\$ but a bit less depending on the cap. value. I have derived this value in a [series of articles](http://www.how2power.com/newsletters/1511/articles/H2PToday1511_design_ONSemi.pdf?NOREDIR=1) I published on the flyback and the impact of the leakage inductance on the small-signal response. As correctly pointed out by Andy aka, the calculations I did neglect this delay.

Comment: @VerbalKint thanks for clarification (I read your mind!).